# CSGO: laggy gameplay on Dell E6510

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

**Problem**

Laggy gameplay in [CSGO](https://store.steampowered.com/app/730/CounterStrike_Global_Offensive/) in offline mode with bots (9 bots + 1 human) with video settings set to low.

[image]

**Hardware**

- [Dell Latitude E6510](https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Shared-Content_data-Sheets_Documents/en/latitude-e6410-e6510-specsheet.pdf)
- Core i5 1st Gen 2.67GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- NVIDIA NVS 3100M 512MB gDDR3
- Windows 10 Home

**Game Minimum Requirements**

- Windows 7/Vista/XP
- Core 2 Duo E6600 or AMD Phenom™ X3 8750 processor or better
- 2 GB RAM
- Video card must be 256 MB or more and should be a DirectX 9-compatible with support for Pixel Shader 3.0
- DirectX 9.0c

**Questions**

1. I want to run CSGO at the lowest video setting possible so that gameplay is smooth. Which settings should I enable/disable?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why was my question down voted without an explanation? That's not constructive  feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but no chance. Your laptop is a business device, which is not made for gaming. The primary purpose of that thing is low power consumption to gain better battery life. Also it's already 10 years old.

With that video card you won't get decent results regardless of your config settings. It's simply not made for gaming and it sucks at 3D (which games usually are).

I've run a few benchmarks and they show an average of 20 to 40 FPS in CS:GO with lowest settings. Even tweaking it further down with custom settings won't help much.